# socat error - unknown option "proxyport:8080"

Tags: proxy, socat

I'm trying to run a simple forwarding proxy through another proxy server.
But as soon as I connect to the opened port (e.g. `curl localhost:9090`) an error is thrown and the connection is closed.

```
$ socat -v TCP-LISTEN:9090,fork PROXY:proxyhost:google.com:80,proxyport:8080
2020/03/01 15:00:00 socat[109218] E parseopts(): unknown option "proxyport:8080"
```

I'm using socat version 1.7.3.2 on May 11 2017 13:28:30

with features -> #define WITH_PROXY 1

I tried this on Suse as well as alpine linux and get the same result.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote to the mailing list and the maintainer made me aware of my mistake.

The parameter value must be seperated by an equals instead of a colon.

```
$ socat -v TCP-LISTEN:9090,fork PROXY:proxyhost:google.com:80,proxyport=8080
```